# how to redirect url to specific url

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect my blog post to specific URL `https://example.com/detailblog.php?my-title&s=9` to `https://example.com/my-title/9`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/blog/([0-9]+)\.php /blog/detailblog/.php?s=$1

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/blog/([0-9]+)\.php /blog/detailblog/.php?s=$1
```

it's not working.

Comment: Neither of the two URLs you have shown contains `/blog/`, so what do you expect those RewriteRules to match here?

Comment: can you help what will rules?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading beginner guides for URL rewriting like: https://aloneonahill.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ and using test tools like: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/.

It seems to me you have not understood the syntax, based on the example you provided.